# How do I get an output of all the lines when analysing logfile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, argparse

The script should be able to run and analyze a logfile when typing the following in the terminal:

```
python loganalyzer.py [filepath_to_logfile] [action]
```

The action specified determines what the script outputs.
When typing ***error*** or ***notice*** as action, the output is:

```
date : message
date : message
date : message
date : message
```

But the script doesn't output all lines... why?

For example, when asking for ***notices*** the output I get is:

```
[Mon Dec 05 14:01:48 2005]  :  workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties

[Mon Dec 05 14:11:40 2005]  :  jk2_init() Found child 6115 in scoreboard slot 10

[Mon Dec 05 14:11:45 2005]  :  workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties

[Mon Dec 05 15:31:06 2005]  :  jk2_init() Found child 6260 in scoreboard slot 7

[Mon Dec 05 15:31:09 2005]  :  jk2_init() Found child 6261 in scoreboard slot 8

[Mon Dec 05 15:31:10 2005]  :  workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties

[Mon Dec 05 15:40:59 2005]  :  jk2_init() Found child 6276 in scoreboard slot 6

[Mon Dec 05 15:41:32 2005]  :  workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties

[Mon Dec 05 15:45:42 2005]  :  jk2_init() Found child 6285 in scoreboard slot 8

[Mon Dec 05 15:45:44 2005]  :  workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties

[Mon Dec 05 15:50:53 2005]  :  jk2_init() Found child 6294 in scoreboard slot 7

[Mon Dec 05 15:51:18 2005]  :  jk2_init() Found child 6296 in scoreboard slot 6

[Mon Dec 05 15:51:20 2005]  :  workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties

[Mon Dec 05 15:55:31 2005]  :  jk2_init() Found child 6302 in scoreboard slot 8

[Mon Dec 05 15:55:32 2005]  :  workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties

[Mon Dec 05 16:01:17 2005]  :  jk2_init() Found child 6310 in scoreboard slot 6

[Mon Dec 05 16:02:00 2005]  :  jk2_init() Found child 6316 in scoreboard slot 7
```

**It's only 17 of 34 lines.**

*Here is all of my code:*

```
import argparse

error = {}
notice = {}
log_file = 'test.log'

#   Functions
def load():
    with open('test.log') as logfile:
        for line in logfile:
            parts = line.split('[error]')
            if len(parts) == 2:
                error[parts[0]] = parts[1]
            parts = line.split('[notice]')
            if len(parts) == 2:
                notice[parts[0]] = parts[1]

def errors():
    for date, info in error.items():
        print(date + ' : ' + info)

def notices():
    for date, info in notice.items():
        print(date + ' : ' + info)
        
def statistics():
    file = open('test.log', 'r')
    error_counter = 0-1
    content = file.read()
    errors = content.split('[error]')

    for error in errors:
        if error:
            error_counter += 1
    print('Errors: ' + str(error_counter))
    
    notice_counter = 0-1
    notices = content.split('[notice]')

    for notice in notices:
        if notice:
            notice_counter += 1
    print('Notices: ' + str(notice_counter))


#   Run
if __name__ == '__main__':
    load()
    notices()

#    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
#    parser.add_argument('logfile', help = 'Run program by typing python.exe logglooker.py [path_to_logfile] [action]')
#    parser.add_argument('notice', help = 'Use this action to output all the date and message of all notice entries.')
#    parser.add_argument('error', help = 'Use this action to output all the data and message of all error entries.')
#    parser.add_argument('statistics', help = 'Use this action to output how many errors and notices it is in the logfile.')
#    args = parser.parse_args()
#    log_file = args.logfile
```

I haven't figure out how to get argparse to work properly yet, thats why the code looks a little weird.

And the test.log to analyze is this.

```
[Mon Dec 05 14:01:48 2005] [notice] workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties
[Mon Dec 05 14:01:48 2005] [error] mod_jk child workerEnv in error state 7
[Mon Dec 05 14:01:48 2005] [notice] workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties
[Mon Dec 05 14:01:48 2005] [error] mod_jk child workerEnv in error state 9
[Mon Dec 05 14:01:48 2005] [notice] workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties
[Mon Dec 05 14:01:48 2005] [error] mod_jk child workerEnv in error state 8
[Mon Dec 05 14:11:40 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6115 in scoreboard slot 10
[Mon Dec 05 14:11:43 2005] [error] [client 141.154.18.244] Directory index forbidden by rule: /var/www/html/
[Mon Dec 05 14:11:45 2005] [notice] workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties
[Mon Dec 05 14:11:45 2005] [error] mod_jk child workerEnv in error state 7
[Mon Dec 05 15:31:06 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6259 in scoreboard slot 6
[Mon Dec 05 15:31:06 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6260 in scoreboard slot 7
[Mon Dec 05 15:31:09 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6261 in scoreboard slot 8
[Mon Dec 05 15:31:10 2005] [notice] workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties
[Mon Dec 05 15:31:10 2005] [error] mod_jk child workerEnv in error state 6
[Mon Dec 05 15:31:10 2005] [notice] workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties
[Mon Dec 05 15:31:10 2005] [error] mod_jk child workerEnv in error state 6
[Mon Dec 05 15:31:10 2005] [notice] workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties
[Mon Dec 05 15:31:10 2005] [error] mod_jk child workerEnv in error state 6
[Mon Dec 05 15:40:59 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6277 in scoreboard slot 7
[Mon Dec 05 15:40:59 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6276 in scoreboard slot 6
[Mon Dec 05 15:41:32 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6280 in scoreboard slot 7
[Mon Dec 05 15:41:32 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6278 in scoreboard slot 8
[Mon Dec 05 15:41:32 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6279 in scoreboard slot 6
[Mon Dec 05 15:41:32 2005] [notice] workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties
[Mon Dec 05 15:41:32 2005] [error] mod_jk child workerEnv in error state 7
[Mon Dec 05 15:41:32 2005] [notice] workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties
[Mon Dec 05 15:41:32 2005] [error] mod_jk child workerEnv in error state 6
[Mon Dec 05 15:41:32 2005] [notice] workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties
[Mon Dec 05 15:41:32 2005] [error] mod_jk child workerEnv in error state 7
[Mon Dec 05 15:45:42 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6285 in scoreboard slot 8
[Mon Dec 05 15:45:44 2005] [notice] workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties
[Mon Dec 05 15:45:44 2005] [error] mod_jk child workerEnv in error state 6
[Mon Dec 05 15:50:53 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6293 in scoreboard slot 6
[Mon Dec 05 15:50:53 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6294 in scoreboard slot 7
[Mon Dec 05 15:51:18 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6297 in scoreboard slot 7
[Mon Dec 05 15:51:18 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6295 in scoreboard slot 8
[Mon Dec 05 15:51:18 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6296 in scoreboard slot 6
[Mon Dec 05 15:51:20 2005] [notice] workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties
[Mon Dec 05 15:51:20 2005] [error] mod_jk child workerEnv in error state 7
[Mon Dec 05 15:51:20 2005] [notice] workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties
[Mon Dec 05 15:51:20 2005] [error] mod_jk child workerEnv in error state 7
[Mon Dec 05 15:51:20 2005] [notice] workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties
[Mon Dec 05 15:51:20 2005] [error] mod_jk child workerEnv in error state 6
[Mon Dec 05 15:55:31 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6302 in scoreboard slot 8
[Mon Dec 05 15:55:32 2005] [notice] workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties
[Mon Dec 05 15:55:32 2005] [error] mod_jk child workerEnv in error state 6
[Mon Dec 05 16:01:17 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6310 in scoreboard slot 6
[Mon Dec 05 16:02:00 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6315 in scoreboard slot 6
[Mon Dec 05 16:02:00 2005] [notice] jk2_init() Found child 6316 in scoreboard slot 7
```

Comment: For `argparse` you might want to specify `parser.add_argument('-a'','--action', choices=['notice', 'error', 'statistics'])`.  Do a `print(args)` to see what the parser did.

Comment: I suddenly figured almost everything out yesterday, and with your help I was able to complete the assignment. Thanks you!