# Python - Read logfile, Analyze it and print out lines, depending on action

Tags: python

I need help with ideas on how to create a Python script that analyzes a log file.

Goal is to run: `python3 analyzer.py [filepath] [action]`

It should print out: errors or notices in each row, depending on action.

`filepath`

- path of the log file
- Valid values for the action are error, notice.
- The action determines what the script outputs.

`action`

- error = print errors in the file
- notice = print notices in the file

This guy had similar: [How do I get an output of all the lines when analysing logfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66930628/how-do-i-get-an-output-of-all-the-lines-when-analysing-logfile)

Tried this so far.

```py
import argparse

# class errors(argparse.Action):
    # def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        # setattr(namespace, self.dest, ' '.join(values))

# parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Parse input string')
# parser.add_argument('string', help='Input String', nargs='+', action=errors)
# parser.add_argument('--extra', '-s', help='Another Option!')

# args = parser.parse_args()
# print(args)

error = {}
notice = {}
log_file = 'log.log'

#   Functions
def load():
    with open('log.log') as logfile:
        for line in logfile:
            parts = line.split('[error]')
            if len(parts) == 2:
                error[parts[0]] = parts[1]
            parts = line.split('[notice]')
            if len(parts) == 2:
                notice[parts[0]] = parts[1]

def errors():
    for date, info in error.items():
        print(date + ' : ' + info)

def notices():
    for date, info in notice.items():
        print(date + ' : ' + info)
          
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    load()
```

Example of logfile **log.log**:

````
[Mon Jan 01 09:01:48 2021] [error] Cannot delete topic 1
[Mon Jan 01 09:01:48 2021] [notice] Scheduling log segment 564002 for log test-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[Mon Jan 01 09:01:48 2021] [error] Cannot delete topic 2
[Mon Jan 01 09:01:48 2021] [notice] <powershell> topic was provided.. running powershell content
[Mon Jan 01 09:01:48 2021] [error] Cannot delete topic 3
[Mon Jan 01 09:11:40 2021] [notice] creating topics
[Mon Jan 01 09:11:43 2021] [error] [client 091.154.18.244] Directory index forbidden by rule: /var/www/ ```
````

Comment: Please share the code you've tried so far!

Comment: Tried this so far, i am new to Python fyi.

Comment: Please put your code in the question

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. What's the specific area you need help with? Your script looks close, but unclear which bit you need help with.

Comment: I get no output when i run the script, i guess i need help with `argparse` part.

Comment: You get no output because you don't call `errors()` and `notices()`, `load()` just make the dictionary without printing anything. By the way, as each key is unique, only the last item is kept when adding items with same key.

Comment: how do i call errors() and notices()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the command-line interface is not necessary, you can just ask for input to do the job.

```
def analyze():
    filepath = input("Filepath: ")
    action = input("Input 'error' or 'notice' to choose output message: ")
    if action not in ['error', 'notice']:
        print("Not supported.")
        return
    with open(filepath) as logfile:
        for line in logfile:
            if action in line:
                parts = line.split(f'[{action}]')
                print(parts[0], parts[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    analyze()
```

Test run:

```
Filepath: log.log
Input 'error' or 'notice' to choose output message: error
[Mon Jan 01 09:01:48 2021]   Cannot delete topic 1

[Mon Jan 01 09:01:48 2021]   Cannot delete topic 2

[Mon Jan 01 09:01:48 2021]   Cannot delete topic 3

[Mon Jan 01 09:11:43 2021]   [client 091.154.18.244] Directory index forbidden by rule: /var/www/
```

---

#### CLI version:

The main part of CLI version is almost the same as input version, we just need to add the argparse part and turn variables to attributes.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Analyze log file.')
# both arguments are positional, which means missing any one of them will raise error
parser.add_argument('filepath', help="Specifies file path.")
# choices restrict the action can be selected
parser.add_argument('action', choices=['error', 'notice'],
                    help='Output error or notice message.')
args = parser.parse_args()

def analyze(args):
    with open(args.filepath) as logfile:
        for line in logfile:
            if args.action in line:
                parts = line.split(f'[{args.action}]')
                print(parts[0], parts[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    analyze(args)
```

Test run:

```
> python analyzer.py log.log notice
[Mon Jan 01 09:01:48 2021]   Scheduling log segment 564002 for log test-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)

[Mon Jan 01 09:01:48 2021]   <powershell> topic was provided.. running powershell content

[Mon Jan 01 09:11:40 2021]   creating topics
```

Comment: Thank you, but CLI is necessary :( <br> I want to run it like this `python3 analyzer.py [filepath] [action]`

Answer (score 0):

Start of by trying this code out.

It takes your existing loop and looks to see if the value `[error]` appears on a line, printing it out if it does.

```py
with open('log.log') as logfile:
    for line in logfile:
        if "[error]" in line:
            print(line)
```

Assuming this works, extending your code to allow a value from the arguments should be relatively simple.

Here's a tip on what you might want to change:

```py
action = "error"
...
if f"[{action}]" in line:
    print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how about the output, right now, there is no output when i run the script, i need help with the argparse and print out the result.